# How to solve hacking php form

Tags: php, javascript

I used livevalidation script to validate php forms but i think that my website was hacked because some inputs allow to insert number not letter.

Another problem hacker make my selection tag insert data wrong not in my form.

So please can anyone help me ?

Comment: It's little Bobby Tables all over again: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thanks for your adivce but I'm a beginner in php developing so can you tell me how can i find a giud to help me

Comment: I'll be the first to admit this isn't my cup of tea :) That was less advice and more "Here's a funny comic about this sort of thing."

Answer (score 11):

Javascript cannot provide a secure way to check data. It should only be considered a convenience to the user.

You need to validate all data you get on the server in PHP.

PS: You may find the [Filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php) functions useful, regular expressions, `in_array()` for validating select boxes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your adivse but I'm a beginner in php developing so can you tell me how can i find a giud to help me

Comment: @maha, that is a very broad question. I don't have any resources at hand (I'm sure others do), but basically you need to check every $_GET or $_POST variable that the form submits and make sure it's what you expect it to be. After searching for some tutorials on the filtering functions and trying out, you could come back and start new questions that address specific things like "how do I validate an email address?" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I can do as :

```
if (isset($_GET['string']) && !empty($_GET['string']) && is_string($_GET['string']))

    $str = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_GET['string'])));
```

And :

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))

    $id = trim($_GET['id']);
```

What do you think this ?

I am not sure of the usefulness of ALL these tests.

Answer (score 0):

download accunetix look for a free version somewhere it will let you test your application for any security holes. it has a great UI and easy to use not like the other crap that exists out there. accunetix.com

Comment: also make sure that every single input on your form is cleaned. no matter if its a checkbox, selection, input, radio , button. hackers will try to modify anythign to make your site do what they want.